# Failed to connect to Remote Ignite Node

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

I have multiple service and one service is master one which is use to create and get cache .
I have one server node , I run all my service on different server on same VPC, my all other service use master service for cache operation .
when I up my other service , it boot up properly and after starting it show failed to connect to node in log it show the IP address of master service server.

How To resolve this ??

ERROR SHOWING IS:
"""

class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=0c7caa96-2fdf-4e00-8f92-a7b690d89815, addrs=[/10.3.0.8:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo/:47100]] site:stackoverflow.com

"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports from a list below are used by `TcpCommunicationSpi`:

> 10.3.0.8:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100

Your services starts client nodes?
Are services and master node in one network or they are in different networks and your service tries to connect from behind the NAT or network filter?

In case of NAT and client nodes you can try this [instruction](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat).

Comment: yes my services start a client node and they are in same network(same VPC)

Comment: Could you investigate on possible blocking of standard ports: 47500, 47100? Nodes should be able to connect on this ports in both directions.